# Как повесить 2 обработчика на одно и тоже событие на чистом js

Tags: javascript

Есть сторонний скрипт который вешает на body.onload обработчик.
Мне в свою очередь нужно использовать это же событие, как повесить обработчик не затерев старый?

Comment: `body.addEventListener("load", [your script]);`

Comment: @Igor оформите Ваш комментарий как ответ

Answer (score 1):

Используйте `addEventListener`, посволяющий прикреплять к событию больше одного обработчика.

```
body.addEventListener("load", function() { [your first script] });
...
body.addEventListener("load", function() { [your second script] });
```